# CSS width with percentage for child elements not working on firefox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to create a fluid layout, so I used a width in %. I tested the site on Chrome, Safari and IE. When it worked fine in IE I thought my work was done, however when checking it in Firefox I realized the width was incorrect. EG: two 50% elements wouldn't fit in one line neither 3 elements with 33% width. This is an example from my site:

http://pranalog.com/example.php

How can I get this to work on Firefox (or on the most browsers)?

Comment: besides the fact that your markup is invalid (missing closing div) it works for me in recent firefox. A common cause for this problem are whitespaces between the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `box-sizing: border-box;` set on the `div`'s, to set `border-box` in Firefox, add:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

to your style rule. This is needed to get [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to work in Firefox, setting this property to `border-box` forces the browser to render the `div`'s with the specified width and height, and places the border and padding inside the `div`'s.

This in turn fixes your issue: with the border rendered on the outside of your `div`'s, the total width of your elements is essentially `3 times 33.3% = 99.9%` plus `6px` needed to render the the six `1px` wide borders on the right and on the left of each `div`. Since `6px` is more than the `0.1%` of the page width that is left, the last `div` doesn't fit on the same line anymore and moves down to the next line.

With the border rendered inside the `div`'s by setting `border-box` properly, you won't have this issue.

Here's a fixed up <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CpQGU/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a border of 1px, try removing the border value and all three fit side by side.

If you would like to keep the border then just reduce the width to around 32%

Good luck

Comment: I made that mistake in the fiddle, however if you see it at my site (no box-sizing and no border) it still happens http://pranalog.com/example.php